# How to delete the data of old table after transferred to new table in a database in sql insert statement

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2008

```
INSERT INTO Checkout(ProductID, MemberID, Quantity) 
SELECT ProductID, MemberID, Quantity FROM Cart WHERE (MemberID = MemberID)
```

How to use the delete statement to delete the old table data after I transferred to the new table?

Comment: Any reason you are using `WHERE (MemberID = MemberID)` ?

Comment: i have to use it to make it work to transfer the data

Comment: please see my answer below...

Comment: What DBMS do you use? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle ....?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Cart WHERE MemberID = MemberID
```

Assuming that MemberID is a variable being passed into the query

Comment: Or, more concisely: DELETE FROM Cart.  Or, more explicitly: DELETE FROM Cart WHERE true.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(MemberID = MemberID)
DELETE FROM Cart WHERE (MemberID = MemberID)'.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DELETE FROM CART C WHERE 
0 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CHECKOUT CO WHERE CO.QUANTITY = C.QUANTITY AND CO.PRODUCTID = C.PRODUCTID AND CO.MEMBERID = C.MEMBERID)
```

The above removes all rows from `CART` which are found in `CHECKOUT` based on the the three columns `MEMBERID, PRODUCTID, QUANTITY` .

BTW: Any reason you are using `WHERE (MemberID = MemberID)` ?

IF the second `MemberID` is a parameter passed into the query I would recommend using a different name for it like `pMemberID`... IF this is the case you could do `DELETE FROM CART WHERE MEMBERID = pMEMBERID` .

Comment: yes memberid=memberid where the =memberid is a value i gave memberid.

Comment: @KayLee For your case you could use the second one... which of the 2 statements I gave you shows this error ?

Comment: syntax error missing operator in query expression for all the suggestions

Comment: @KayLee sorry but that is technically not possible (esp. with the second statement) - just tried it here...